# System.Reflection.TargetException. return value null error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, null

I have a problem still cannot solve it. I have an db and in save button dropdown list has null problem.

null problem is in this line

```
var ulke = db.Ulkeler.Where(m => m.Id == model.Ulke.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Would you help me to solve this?

there is also database and the dropdown form.

personel.cs

```
namespace grid.Models
{
    [Table("Personeller")]
    public class Personel
    {
        [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50),Required]
    public string Adi { get; set; }
    public string Soyadi { get; set; }
    public int Yas { get; set; }

    public Ulke Ulke { get; set; }

}
}
```

Ulke.cs

```
namespace grid.Models
{
    [Table("Ulkeler")]
    public class Ulke
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Ad { get; set; }

    public List<Personel> Personeller { get; set; }
}
}
```

cshtml side

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="txt-ulke"></span>
        </div>


        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Ulke, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Ulkeler, new { @class = "form-control", aria_describedby = "txt_ulke" })
    </div>
```

save button -grid controller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ekle(Personel model)
    {
        var ulke = db.Ulkeler.Where(m => m.Id == model.Ulke.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        model.Ulke = ulke;

        db.Personeller.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Listele");
    }
```

here is the problem

```
[TargetException: Statik olmayan metot, hedef gerektirir.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target) +12788592
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +115
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +54
   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture) +61
   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) +21
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression me, Object instance, Object& memberValue) +195
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression) +332
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +1216
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6() +39
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +154
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +279
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +40
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +113
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +99
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +211
   grid.Controllers.GridController.Ekle(Personel model) in E:\hande\çalışma\mvc\grid-mvc-udemy\grid\grid\Controllers\GridController.cs:46
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +103
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +576
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem more clearly (in the question, not as a comment). What does "dropdown list has null problem" mean?

Comment: What's the concrete problem? What do you mean by "null problem"?

Comment: ı added but i don't know it helped or not. when i select somthing from dropdown says it is null. I see the countries. I don't know what i do wrong

Comment: Is `model.Ulke` null by chance?

Comment: probably not but when i try breakpoint i haven't see the problem. because i am still learning. It is something ulke and dropdownlist

Comment: I rearrange the question to see clear